# Will numpy.save() always convert lists to arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, save

If I do

```
import numpy as np 
h = [1,2,3]
np.save("h.npy",h)
h = np.load("h.npy")
print(type(h))
```

the result is

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Is this always the case? Is it the same for `np.savez()`? In the [online documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.save.html) it just says that `h` should be array-like.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will.

Internally, [`numpy.save`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.save.html#numpy.save) is using [`np.asanyarray`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.asanyarray.html#numpy.asanyarray) over the data, as can be seen in the [source code for `np.save`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.19.0/numpy/lib/npyio.py#L527) and in the [source code for `np.savez`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.19.0/numpy/lib/npyio.py#L718).